# How to avoid ASP.NET SqlServer session to interfer with the ambient Transaction-Per-Request?

Tags: asp.net, session-state, transactions

I am trying to use a transaction scope in a transaction-per-request pattern. So I have a http module that do (simplified):

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew);
    PutScopeInHttpContext(scope);
}

private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scope = GetScopeFromHttpContext();
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Error == null)
        {
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        scope.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then, in my web.config, I have:

```
<httpModules>
    <clear/>
    <add name="OutputCache" type="System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule"/>
    <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    <add name="Profile" type="System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule"/>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="TransactionPerRequestWebModule" type="Acme.Web.TransactionPerRequestWebModule, Acme.Web"/>
</httpModules>
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;" cookieless="false" timeout="360"/>
```

Now, at what seem like randomly rate, roughly 1 page out of ten gives me the following error:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.]
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1951450
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849003
  System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
  System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +89
  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean getExclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server session database.]
  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.ThrowSqlConnectionException(SqlConnection conn, Exception e) +229
  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.DoGet(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean getExclusive, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +649
  System.Web.SessionState.SqlSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actionFlags) +48
  System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem() +117
  System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +487
  System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +66
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

What I (think I) understand is that the connection to the ASP.NET session database is sometimes enlisted in my business transaction, and I get this error when my business transaction is completing first.

There is a couple of problem with that:

- I don't think the transaction for the session state should be the same as my business one. These are 2 separate concerns.
- It makes the transaction automatically escalate to a distributed (MSDTC) one, which impacts my performance.

  How do I decouple my business transaction from the ASP.NET session one?

  Thanks in advance,

  Julien

Answer (score 2):

This is a Necro-Answering, but the answer to the question in case anyone else comes across this randomly while Googling is to add `Enlist=False` to the `SqlServerSessionState connection string`.

Due to odd timing, the connection used to retrieve session can sometimes enlist in an ambient transaction, even though you probably would prefer that it wouldn't.

Setting `Enlist=False` on the connection string ensures that your session state connections won't pick up the ambient transaction and thus cause a nice fast transaction to get promoted to a slower distributed transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of how your code is working, but you can suppress the ambient transaction like this, which may help:

```
using(TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
     try
     {
          //Start of non-transactional section 
          using(TransactionScope scope2 = new
             TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
          {
               //Do non-transactional work here
          }
          //Restores ambient transaction here
   }
     catch
     {}
   //Rest of scope1
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Balazs. I may have not be clear. I need a business transaction, so I don't want to suppress it. It is just that I need it to be different from the ASP.NET session one.

Comment: It would only be suppressed within the scope of that inner using block. So, do whatever session-related work you have to do within that block. The session-related work would still be covered by a transaction (scope2). However, a failure within the inner transaction would not affect the outer transaction.  That's all the "Suppress" option does.  It just causes the containing transaction scope to ignore that block of code.

Am I still not understanding your question?